# CSS white-space: nowrap causes container to expand to fit all text

Tags: css

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior in which a an element with `overflow: hidden`, `white-space: nowrap`, and a `width: 50%` forces its containing element to expand to fit all the text even though it is constrained by the width declaration (and not actually visible). Setting a specific width on the container or using `overflow: hidden` also does nothing to help. Setting an absolute value as width for the element in question however, fixes the problem, but i do not want to use absolute values.

Example: http://jsbin.com/loxuz/3 (Yellow box should only be 50% of grey box, but is expanding to fit all of the text in the blue box, even though that is restricted in width.)

Does anyone see anything obviously wrong here? Should the containing elements have a width, and could it have anything to do with the fact that I'm using percentages? I don’t feel that could be the case as the width should be inherited from containers upwards, right? And not be dictated form text elements downwards. The only explanation I can find is that `white-space: nowrap` is causing this. Removing this gives the container the right width, but also causes wrapping of the text, which I don’t want.

Does anyone know a solution to this, or have any insight? :)

Comment: Try not using a fieldset, I believe it's the computed styling, change your fieldset to a div.

Comment: I'm using a reset stylesheet if you're thinking about default styling. Might look like whitespace: nowrap was interfering not with the immidate container but something futher up, investigating futher...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick workaround for the issue with fieldsets not respecting the specified width is to add a `min-width: 0` to the element:

i.e.

```
fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me... I'm not sure I even want to know why setting a *minimum* width of 0 fixes an object that is clearly wider than 0.

Comment: Thanks so much! It was the `fieldset` all along. Questionable, whether this is an old and persisting quirk, or if there’s a technical reasoning for it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? [**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/tifefase/1/**](http://jsbin.com/tifefase/1/edit). You should remove `max-width: 50%` from `span` and write `width: 50%` for `#second` div. This is the answer you are looking for if you want to use `fieldset`.

```
#second {
  width:50%; 
  border:yellow 1px solid;
}

span {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  outline:blue 1px solid;
  display:block;
}
```

But if you use `div` instead of fieldset, You can carry on with your current values. [**SEE THE NEW DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/tifefase/3/edit) with `div` being used instead of `fieldset`.

```
#second {
  width:50%; 
}

#third {
  width:100%; 
  border:yellow 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying this is caused by using tags fieldset and section? What i want is for the yellow box to fill whatever space it is given by its parent and clip of any content exceeding this width, and for the blue box to not wrap text.

Comment: I have updated my answer. http://jsbin.com/tifefase/3/edit Now, you can see, that yellow box is filling up with whatever space it has been given by its parent. And yes, using fieldset occupies the full width even though when you want it to take the width given by its parent.

Comment: I tested this in my actual code, removing fieldset does the trick. I'm supprised at this, as i have never had any real problems with fieldset before, and assumed it just worked like a div. Do you care do give any more detail as to why the fieldset seem to honor the expanding child element (with white-space:norwap)?

Comment: I put my brain into work to think out the 'WHY' part but it seems that I can only state, width doesn't work on fieldset when `white-space: nowrap;` is applied. But reasoning wise, I have no clue.

Comment: If you feel that I answered your question, you can mark it as the right answer :)